# Determine the form of solution to differential equation, for particular starting value

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am working on a differential equations problem.

I must first find the general solution to:

$$y' = y(y-1),$$

where $x$ is the dependent variable.

I have managed to solve this, to get the answer:

$$y(x) = \frac{1}{1-Ae^x}.$$

Then I must find an explicit solution which solves the initial value problem $y(0) = y_0.$
My solution for this part of the problem is:

$$y(x) = \frac{1}{1-(\frac{y_0 - 1}{y_0})e^x}.$$

The final part of the problem asks 'What form does this solution take for the particular values $y_0 = 0, y_0 = 1$ and $y_0 = 2$?'

Seeing that there will be an issue with dividing by $0$ when $y_0 = 0$, I am not sure how to progress with the problem.
I would appreciate a hint, in order to solve this.

Comment: the differential equation $y' = y(y-1)$ has two constant solutions $y = 0$ and $y=1.$ by uniqueness, no other solution can cross these.

Comment: What do you mean by 'no other solution can cross these', please?

Comment: if you look at the graphs of solution $y$ that has the initial value $y_0$ at $x = 0,$( these are called phase portraits), you will see that this portrait has three distinct regions. they are separated by the lines $y=0$ and $y = 1.$ these act as barriers in the sense that the solutions starting in each region stay in them(regions are invariant).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should see that since $y=0$ is a root of the right side that $y\equiv 0$ is a steady state or constant solution, as is $y\equiv 1$.

Secondly, you can transform your final expression to
$$
y(x) = \frac{y_0}{y_0-(y_0 - 1)e^x}.
$$
which is also valid for $y_0=0$.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean $y_{0}=y(0)$ so that $x_{0}=0$. As you rightly point out, the initial value problem

$y'=y(y-1)\\y(0)=0$

cannot be solved by separation of variables. The same problem arises if $y_{0}=1$ and the solution is similar:

Since $F(x,y)=y(y-1)$ has a continuous partial derivative in $y$ you know there is a unique solution. Can you find it by inspection?

Comment: Why does the same problem arise if $y_0 = 1$?  In that case, there is no issue with dividing by $0$.

Comment: I have not yet studied partial derivatives, but can research them.

Answer (score 0):

$y(x)=0$ and $y(x)=1$ are solution of the differential equation. By uniqueness these are the only solutions with the initial conditions $y(0)=0$ and $y(0)=1$ respectively. In your solution, in fact, you were supposing that $y\neq0,1$ everywhere.